# Changing symbology of layer created using Select Tool using arcgis web app

Tags: symbology, web-mapping, arcgis-online

We have an arcgis online app that allows users to select features with the option of 'create a layer'.  When the new layer is created from the selection it mimics the symbology of the original layer.

**Is there a way for our customers to change the symbology of the layer they create?**

[image: Creating Layer from Select Tool]